# PHP memory_get_peak_usage is showing different for development server and production server

Tags: php

I am using same script for development and production server. The script is below.

```
    // my content.....



    // my content ends here

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('filename.xlsx');

    echo ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;


    echo " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
    exit;
```

the above script shows below result on development server

```
  Current memory usage: 11.5 MB
  Peak memory usage: 14 MB
```

but when i run it on my production server i got below

```
  Current memory usage: 67 MB
  Peak memory usage: 70 MB
```

Note:the data is 100% same for the my content area. And development environment and production environments are same( IIS 7.5 PHP 5.4)
why this is happening?

Comment: Is the memory usage before `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');` the same between the servers ?

Comment: Yes! It is same. 0.75MB

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have the same memory usage before the `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');`, I can think of 2 options here :

1. The $objPHPExcel is different (I doubt this)
2. One server has x86 arhitecture and the other a x64 (but I find the difference here a bit too big)

PS : Maybe `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter` creates a different object on the servers if it is a container, dump the `$objWriter` before the save and see if it is of the same type.